# How to center a UITableView in a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

My table has about 5 items. The table, which is created through IB, appears at the top of view.. How would I center the UItableView such that it appears lower (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9QoS.png)

Thanks

Edit:
Answer is to modify the frame and assign it a CGRect in viewDidAppear method

```
self.menuitems.frame=CGRectMake(self.menuitems.frame.origin.x,200.0,self.menuitems.frame.size.width,self.menuitems.frame.size.height);
```

Thanks to AAAAAAAAA and slev

Comment: use tableview.center=self.view.center

Comment: I added that line of code in viewDidLoad however it does not work. The table still appears at the top

Comment: print the tableview frame in the the log statement

Comment: did you mean center from up side ?

Comment: change the tableview frame what ever you want like tableview.frame=CGRectmake(50,50,200,200)

Comment: Try adding `tableview.frame = self.view.center`, like @AAAAAAAAA suggested, in `viewDidAppear:` instead of in `viewDidLoad`.  Chances are the view hasn't fully initialized in the `viewDidLoad` method.  By the time `viewDidAppear:` is called, the view is set and has a valid frame to use for initializing other visual objects on it, like your tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better way you can directly modify the frame of the tableView.
like

```
tableView.frame=CGRectMake(your frame dimensions what ever you want );
```

Comment: Modifying the frame does not work either. Keep in mind the table is created through IB.

Comment: Alede even we added tableview through the IB we can change the frame of that according to our requirement.

Comment: Piece of code has to be added to viewDidAppear as opposed to viewDidLoad as mentioned by slev.

Thanks again A*9